# Как правильно повторить строку N раз через запятую python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка `string='%s'`. И переменная `num=5`. Хочется получить `num` дубликатов строки `string`, но не рядом друг с другом, а через `', '`.
Существует ли более оптимальный способ, чем делать `.join` массива через `range(num)`?

К примеру:

```
string = '%s'
num = 5
# result = '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s'
result = ', '.join([string for _ in range(num)])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string = '%s'
num = 5

string += ', '
result = (num * str)[:-2]
```

`[:-2]` значит исключить последние 2 знака, т.е. `,`  .

Comment: Экзотичненько, Оно будет быстрее `join`'а?

Comment: @Gh0sTG0, да, быстрее — приблизительно 392 ns против 462 ns, как показывает `timeit`

Comment: Ага, спасибо @MarianD

Answer (score 2):

Построение списка можно немного сократить:

```py
string = '%s'
num = 5
print(', '.join([string] * num))
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Т. е. `[string for _ in range(num)]` заменить на `[string] * num`

*PS: называйте переменные нормально.*

Comment: *Глюкануло, переименовал переменные нормально.* Работает, спасибо. PS Приму через 5 минут, раньше не даст.